# Appearance on website

Tags: professionalism, team

I have been working for seven months in a team of four people on a new project. There are three additional members who occasionally get small tasks assigned, and are therefore loosely related to the project. All members except for the team lead have the same job title, but different seniority in the company, me having the least seniority. One of the additional team members was responsible for creating a project website which also contains a team page. Today I saw the page and noticed that the sequence is team lead, team members, additional team members, me. There is a profile photo next to each name except for my name. I also haven't been asked if I can provide a photo, which makes me feel being demoted and left out. I don't know how to approach this situation without appearing entitled or getting laughed at or ridiculed.

I'm going to leave the company after the project, as it's not a good fit interpersonally. If a recruiter or other people google my name and see the team page, they could get the impression that I have a subordinate role which is not the case. So I either want to appear higher on the team page with a photo, or even better, not appear on the page at all so I can argue that the page is not up to date. How could I approach this situation?

Comment: Have you tried talking to this team member and asking why your information on the website isn't up to date?

Comment: Not yet as I'm not sure which approach is better / more professional

Comment: `If a recruiter or other people google my name and see the team page`, you overestimated how much attention people will pay when shuffling names. Less than 5% of people will ever google your name if they have your CV, and they won't really bother to check where's your photo in your former company's page. If someone really raised the question, you can simply say `oh they didn't update that page for years ;)`

Comment: @tweray Yes, I probably overestimate the attention of other people paying attention to name on a website, but I'm proud of my work and don't want my name associated in that way.

Comment: They also might remove you from the team list once the project is over. Do they already know you are leaving the company soon?

Answer (score 6):

> If a recruiter or other people google my name and see the team page they could get the impression that I have a subordinate role which is not the case so I either want to appear higher on the team page with a photo or even better not appear on the page at all so I can argue that the page is not up to date.

Honestly you're overthinking this.

Even if they **do** google you and go on to that page it's extremely unlikely that they will jump to the conclusions that concern you.

No pic on website = they didn't have one on hand. Maybe they didn't have one, maybe the person didn't want their pic on the website. *Oh, they must be subordinate!* just isn't a logical follow on.

> I don't know how to approach this situation without appearing entitled or getting laughed at or ridiculed.

Honestly I'm not sure they would go to laughing at you, but more importantly I just don't think it's necessary in the first place (see above). But if you really, really wanted to address this you could email the appropriate content person for that page and ask

> I noticed my pic is missing on the [xyz] page - do you want me to send one to use?

But I really, really wouldn't bother.